Can someone please help me interpret this info?
I ran a test and this was the info that showed up.
pCPU 14 
Pass 0 
Test 8 
Failing Address 0018e61ac718 (99.5GB)
Expected 0a2f35eeda2270f3
Found 4a2f35eeda2270f3


there's about 2 forks of memtest at least. I feel like this is the one time a photo of your screen is acceptable/useful in giving folks more useful information in helping you interpret what's going on.

Is it always that address? Is it always CPU 14? More info is needed but basically the test wrote one piece of data to memory and got a different bit of data back. The 0 at the front changed to a 4.

@JourneymanGeek Hey I updated it with a photo

@Mokubai Do you know any other tests that I could run?

If you re-run the test is it always the same address and CPU?

@Mokubai I just ran a few more tests and added there results to the post. Does this help at all?

You're going to have to go removing memory sticks to find out which might be faulty. There's definitely something wrong there.

@Mokubai Thank you for the help. What am I looking for in a stick? Is it likely to just not work?

You are basically trying to find which stick exhibits those errors. What you have is an occasional bit that is either not being set or is flipping on its own over time. First thing to do would be to check that all the modules are well fitted and contacts are clean. Then test each module individually. Check your motherboard manual for which slots to populate first.
